# Disable SCSS Linting without a comment

Tags: css, unicode, sass, lint

I've got an SCSS file with a charset directive on the first line.

```
@charset 'UTF-8';
```

And we use scss-lint to enforce single quotes alongside a whole bunch of other things.

The problem is, the `@charset` directive doesn't seem to work unless you use double quotes. So I tried to use the scss-disable comment directive.

```
// scss-lint:disable SingleQuotes
@charset "UTF-8";
// scss-lint:enable SingleQuotes
```

For some reason, this didn't work at all. The linter still caught the double quotes as an error. I checked out the disable all option, which seemed to do the trick.

```
// scss-lint:disable all
@charset "UTF-8";
// scss-lint:enable all
```

But it turns out, the `@charset` has to be the very first thing in the file.

For reference, we need to explicitly specify UTF-8, because we're using unicode characters in a `content` insertion. My development machine assumes Unicode and it builds fine, but our CI server won't build unless we include the directive.

Is there a better way to handle this, than just excluding the files with unicode from our linting list?

Comment: Did you get this eventually?

Comment: Afraid not, we ended up using a new build environment that didn't complain about it.

Comment: Ugh. I get the benefits of strict development environments, but it can really get in you way sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply removing the line? According to the official SASS documentation if none is set it assumes that it is UTF-8 as a standard!

> Encodings
>
> When running on Ruby 1.9 and later, Sass is aware of the character
>   encoding of documents. Sass follows the CSS spec to determine the
>   encoding of a stylesheet, and falls back to the Ruby string encoding.
>   This means that it first checks the Unicode byte order mark, then the
>   @charset declaration, then the Ruby string encoding. If none of these
>   are set, it will assume the document is in UTF-8.

Same goes for W3 if you add UTF-8 Encoding as HTML standard:

> You should always use UTF-8 as the character encoding of your style
>   sheets and your HTML pages, and declare that encoding in your HTML. If
>   you do that, there is no need to declare the encoding of your style
>   sheet.

Comment: Yeah, we have. It works fine in my local dev environment, but our CI server refuses to build without it.